# PHP and JSON from Openstreetmap search

Tags: php, json, null, openstreetmap

I am trying to use Openstreetmap and PHP to point to a place on a map.
As you can see below, I retrieve a JSON array, but PHP returns a **NULL value**.

Note that my `$url` is a valid JSON (you can check it [here](http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidate)).

```
<?
$url = 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/Piazza%20Duomo%20Trento?format=json&addressdetails=1&limit=1&polygon_svg=1';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonout = json_decode($html);
echo $jsonout[0];
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to `echo` object that why its given **NULL**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

First of all, your openning tag is not correct :

```
<? ----> <?php
```

Then, you cannot `echo` an array like that. Use `var_dump` on your array to see the structure.

When I try your code with the corrections, I got this :

```
array (size=1)


0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'place_id' => string '8577656' (length=7)
      public 'licence' => string 'Data Â© OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright' (length=84)
      public 'osm_type' => string 'node' (length=4)
      public 'osm_id' => string '924463183' (length=9)
      public 'boundingbox' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => string '46.0675164' (length=10)
          1 => string '46.0676164' (length=10)
          2 => string '11.1217498' (length=10)
          3 => string '11.1218498' (length=10)
      public 'lat' => string '46.0675664' (length=10)
      public 'lon' => string '11.1217998' (length=10)
      public 'display_name' => string 'Piazza Duomo, Piazza del Duomo, centro storico Trento, Trento, TN, TAA, 38122, Italia' (length=85)
      public 'class' => string 'highway' (length=7)
      public 'type' => string 'bus_stop' (length=8)
      public 'importance' => float 0.311
      public 'icon' => string 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/transport_bus_stop2.p.20.png' (length=79)
      public 'address' => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public 'bus_stop' => string 'Piazza Duomo' (length=12)
          public 'pedestrian' => string 'Piazza del Duomo' (length=16)
          public 'suburb' => string 'centro storico Trento' (length=21)
          public 'city' => string 'Trento' (length=6)
          public 'county' => string 'TN' (length=2)
          public 'state' => string 'TAA' (length=3)
          public 'postcode' => string '38122' (length=5)
          public 'country' => string 'Italia' (length=6)
          public 'country_code' => string 'it' (length=2)
      public 'svg' => string 'cx="11.1217998" cy="-46.067566399999997"' (length=40)
```

Comment: `var_dump($jsonout[0]);` and a similar one like `var_dump($jsonout[0]['lat']);` both return `NULL`.

Comment: That's strange, [this code](https://gist.github.com/yoannfleurydev/924320acc8180caf34d2) is working for me. Maybe there is a problem with your config or your network. But that's not a PHP problem here.

Comment: I am starting to think that my provider is blocking this type of procedure. The PHP should really work as it is.

Comment: I doubt that your ISP is blocking this kind of thing. Maybe you should try to get the JSON in an other way. Using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for example.

Comment: My ISP had a constraint. I was finally able to unblock it.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, except for trying to output an array with the following statement

```
echo $jsonout[0];
```

Which will throw a `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Everything is ok.

If this is about accessing the members of the `json_decode` return, see below

`$jsonout` is an array with one element,
that one element is an object, you can access its members like this

```
print $jsonout[0]->licence;
```

Which will output

```
Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
```

If you'd like an associative array, you can pass the second argument for `json_decode`, like this

```
$jsonout = json_decode($html,true);
print $jsonout[0]['display_name'];
```

Which will decode the json into an associative array and will display in a similar way

```
Piazza Duomo, Piazza del Duomo, centro storico Trento, Trento, TN, TAA, 38122, Italia
```

Comment: Still nothing.  `var_dump($jsonout[0]['display_name']);` is NULL.

Comment: Its an object array, So you need to used `var_dump($jsonout[0]->display_name);`

Comment: Using `var_dump($jsonout[0]->display_name);` returns `NULL` as well.

Comment: take it step by step, and do a `var_dump($jsonout);` immediately after `json_decode` and edit your question with the output

Answer (score 0):

please use print_r() in place of echo

```
$url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/Piazza%20Duomo%20Trento?format=json&addressdetails=1&limit=1&polygon_svg=1";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonout = json_decode($html);
print_r($jsonout[0]);
```

and you will get your result.

Answer (score 0):

or you can print `$jsonout[0]["license"]`